# How handle multiple streams in Flutter with signalr, firebase messaging and flutter local notifications

Tags: flutter, stream, firebase-cloud-messaging, signalr

I wrote a flutter application (version 3.7.12), debuging/using Android (iOS and Web not configured) and I have my back end API written in .NET 7 which implements SignalR.
Both the Flutter application and the back end are configured for firebase use (authentication, storage, notifications...).
Everything works very well! Except end to end...
The steps are:

- I send a message - ok
- The ChatService sends the message in the api - ok
- It is received by the API, sent to the database then a notification is triggered via firebase - ok
  Then a new message arrives (via another user/application instance):
- A message is received in the ChatService - KO
  The moment it is going to be added to the new message stream, the local storage flutter notification appears (along with the message) and the new message become null, nothing is even printed in the console even if it is well recieved and seen in the parameter "args".
  This is the method in the chat_service.dart :

```
void _handleIncomingMessage(List<dynamic>? args) {
    final msg = MessageEntity(
        content: args?[1] as String? ?? "",
        id: args?[2],
        senderId: args?[0] as String? ?? "",
        sentAt: DateTime.now(),
        userEntity: UserEntity(
            id: args?[0] as String? ?? ""));
    _messageController.add(msg);
    print("Message added to stream: $msg");
  }
```

I use, in Flutter, these packages:

```
firebase_messaging: ^14.4.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^14.0.0+1
signalr_core: ^1.1.1
```

I implemented a service for the signalr hub:

**i_chat_service.dart**

```
abstract class IChatService {
  Future<void> initSignalR(BuildContext context);
  Future<void> sendMessage(String user, String message, String conversationId);
  void dispose();
  Future<void> sendTypingNotification(String conversationId, String userId);
  Future<void> joinGroup(String conversationId);
  Stream<String> get onTypingNotification;
  Stream<MessageEntity> get onNewMessage;
}
```

**chat_service.dart (shortened for clarity)**

```
class ChatService implements IChatService {
  final AuthHttpClient _authHttpClient;

  late HubConnection? _hubConnection;
  final BehaviorSubject<String?> _typingController = BehaviorSubject<String?>();
  final BehaviorSubject<MessageEntity> _messageController =
      BehaviorSubject<MessageEntity>();

  ChatService(this._authHttpClient);

  @override
  Future<void> initSignalR(BuildContext context) async {
    _hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(
            dotenv["ChatHubURL"] ?? "",
            HttpConnectionOptions(
              transport: HttpTransportType.webSockets,
              client: _authHttpClient,
              logMessageContent: true,
            ))
        .withAutomaticReconnect([500, 1000, 2000, 3000]).build();

    _hubConnection!.onclose((error) {
      print('SignalR connection closed: $error');
    });

    _hubConnection!.on('ReceiveMessage', _handleIncomingMessage);
    _hubConnection!.on('ReceiveTypingNotification', _handleTypingNotification);

    await _hubConnection!.start();
  }

  Future<void> _ensureConnectionActive() async {
    if (!isConnectionActive()) {
      await _hubConnection!.stop();
      await _hubConnection!.start();
    }
  }

  bool isConnectionActive() {
    return _hubConnection != null &&
        _hubConnection!.state == HubConnectionState.connected;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> sendMessage(
      String user, String message, String conversationId) async {
    await _ensureConnectionActive();

    await _hubConnection!.invoke('SendMessage', args: <Object>[
      user,
      message,
      conversationId,
    ]);
  }

  void _handleIncomingMessage(List<dynamic>? args) {
    final msg = MessageEntity(
        content: args?[1] as String? ?? "",
        id: args?[2],
        senderId: args?[0] as String? ?? "",
        sentAt: DateTime.now(),
        userEntity: UserEntity(
            id: args?[0] as String? ?? ""));
    _messageController.add(msg);
    print("Message added to stream: $msg");
  }

  @override
  Stream<MessageEntity> get onNewMessage => _messageController.stream;
}
```

This chat service is used in this widget (shortened for clarity) :

```
class ConversationsDetailsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final MessagesEntity? messagesEntity;

  const ConversationsDetailsWidget({required this.messagesEntity, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ConversationsDetailsWidget> createState() =>
      _ConversationsDetailsWidgetState();
}

class _ConversationsDetailsWidgetState
    extends State<ConversationsDetailsWidget> {
  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
  final chatService = getIt<IChatService>();
  List<MessageEntity> _messages = [];
  final Map<String, String> _usernames = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initSignalR();
// ... (shortened for clarity)
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    chatService.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _typingEndStreamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

void _onSend() {
    if (_messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      final myUserId = getIt<IUserService>().getUserId() ?? "";
      
     chatService.sendMessage(
        myUserId,
        _messageController.text,
        widget.messagesEntity?.conversationId ?? "",
      );
      _typingEndStreamController.add(null);
      _messageController.clear();
      _messageController.clearComposing();
      _scrollToBottom();
    }
  }

  Future<void> initSignalR() async {
    await chatService.initSignalR(context);
    await chatService
        .joinGroup(widget.messagesEntity!.conversationId!);
  }
// ... (shortened for clarity) - this is the widget tree

Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<MessageEntity>(
                  stream: chatService.onNewMessage,
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<MessageEntity> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      final newMessage = snapshot.data!;
                      final username = _usernames[newMessage.senderId] ?? "";
                      final updatedMessage = MessageEntity(
                        content: newMessage.content,
                        id: newMessage.id,
                        senderId: newMessage.senderId,
                        sentAt: newMessage.sentAt,
                        userEntity: UserEntity(
                          id: newMessage.senderId,
                          username: username
                        ),
                      );
                      if (_messages.isEmpty ||
                          _messages.last.id != newMessage.id) {
                        _messages = [..._messages, updatedMessage];
                        _scrollToBottom();
                      }
                    }
                    return MessageListWidget(
                      messages: _messages,
                      myUserId: myUserId ?? '',
                      scrollController: _scrollController,
                      usernames: _usernames,
                    );
                  }),
            ),
```

And finally I implemented firebase messaging and also flutter local notification.
Both are initialized in the main.dart.
Flutter local notification is used here :

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
      _showNotification(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin,
          notification.title ?? '', notification.body ?? '');
    }
  });

Future _showNotification(
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin,
    String title,
    String body) async {
  const androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel_id', 'channel_name',
      importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high, showWhen: false);
  const iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = DarwinNotificationDetails();
  const platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'item x');
}
```

If I remove the local flutter notification called in the FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen, the whole chat system works. The messages are added to the stream and therefore displayed in the StreamBuilder.
I just don't understand what's going on. Looks like the local flutter notification is "stealing" the thread of execution code.
Has anyone encountered this before?
I didn't plan to manage notifications directly in the ChatService since Firebase Messaging has its own stream.
Is it the fact of having several streams running like that at the same time? Is there the possibility of maybe giving a priority order / a queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems the bug was not due to the interaction of signalR, flutter local notification and firebase messaing.

I found another bug where the signalR instance was not re-created.
I added a constructor :

```
ChatService.create(String conversationId, this._authHttpClient) {
    initSignalR(conversationId);
  }
```

And called it like this inside _ConversationsDetailsWidgetState :

```
late final ChatService _chatService;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _chatService = ChatService.create(
        widget.messagesEntity?.conversationId ?? "", getIt<AuthHttpClient>());
    // ...
  }
```

This is sadly not using DI and get it but it solved the problem.